# Modify string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have bash shell script to modify string.

I want get `14040116` (YYMMDDHH) from string `44[tip] 3764d6b8ae82 2014-04-01 16:34 +0400 igor`

My current script looks like

```
raw_info="44[tip] 3764d6b8ae82 2014-04-01 16:34 +0400 igor"

hg_date=`echo $raw_info | cut -d' ' -f 3`
hg_date=${hg_date//-/}
hg_date=${hg_date:2}
hg_hour=`echo $raw_info | cut -d' ' -f 4 | cut -d':' -f 1`

hg_rev=${hg_date}${hg_hour}
```

It works, but can it be shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the specific part of the string where the date is and then use `date` format controls to print it properly:

```
$ raw_info="44[tip] 3764d6b8ae82 2014-04-01 16:34 +0400 igor"
$ date -d"$(cut -d' ' -f3-4 <<< "$raw_info")" "+%y%m%d%H"
14040116
```

To store it into a variable, nest `$()`:

```
$ hg_rev=$(date -d"$(cut -d' ' -f3-4 <<< "$raw_info")" "+%y%m%d%H")
$ echo "$hg_rev"
14040116
```

By pieces:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f3-4 <<< "$raw_info"   #get 3rd and 4th fields from the string
2014-04-01 16:34

$ date -d"2014-04-01 16:34" "+%y%m%d%H"  #convert date into YYMMDDHH format
14040116
```

as from `man date`:

```
   %y     last two digits of year (00..99)
   %m     month (01..12)
   %d     day of month (e.g., 01)
   %H     hour (00..23)
```

Comment: Any reason you're using cut here rather than PE?

Comment: ...anyhow, ended up opting to add my own answer.

Comment: Ah, Parameter Expansion!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` solution.

```
echo "44[tip] 3764d6b8ae82 2014-04-01 16:34 +0400 igor" | awk '{split($3,a,"-");split($4,b,":");print substr(a[1],3,2)a[2]a[3]b[1]}'
14040116
```

- `split($3,a,"-")` divides the 3rd field by `-`, so `2014-04-01` gives `a[1]=2014`, `a[2]=04`, `a[3]=01`.
- `split($4,b,":")`divides the 4th field by `:`, so `16:34` gives `b[1]=16`, `b[2]=34`.

Then `print`:

- `substr(a[1],3,2)` gives last two digits of `2014`, that is, `14`.
- `a[2]a[3]b[1]` gives `14040116`.

Answer (score 1):

While (IMHO) @fedorqui's solution is the best, you can also employ `sed`, eg.

```
sed 's/.* \(2.\)\(..\)-\(..\)-\(..\) \(..\):.*/\2\3\4\5/' <<<"$raw_info"
```

what prints

```
14040116
```

*Ps: it depends on two-digit format and 2xxx year*

Answer (score 1):

Every solution given thus far is invoking external commands, and thus needlessly inefficient.

The much more efficient approach is to use bash's built-in string manipulation tooling.

```
raw_info="44[tip] 3764d6b8ae82 2014-04-01 16:34 +0400 igor"
read -r tip_name hash ymd hour _ <<<"$raw_info"
hg_rev="${ymd:2:2}${ymd:5:2}${ymd:8:2}${hour%%:*}"
```